# dropwizard hibernate Named query not known

Tags: java, hibernate, dropwizard

I have one entity which is the Product entity:

```
package com.amitbaz.tradingsystem;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import org.hibernate.annotations.DynamicUpdate;
import org.hibernate.annotations.NamedQueries;
import org.hibernate.annotations.NamedQuery;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Table;

@DynamicUpdate(true)
@Table(appliesTo = "productTable")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "com.amitbaz.tradingsystem.product.GetAll", query= "select p from Product p"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "com.amitbaz.tradingsystem.product.GetByName", query= "select p from Product p where p.fullName like :name")

})
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="product_name")
    private String fullName;

    @Column(name="product_info")
    private String info;

    @Column(name="product_price")
    private float price;

    @Column(name="product_base_currency")
    private String baseCurrency;

    public Product(String fullName, String info, float price, String baseCurrency) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.info = info;
        this.price = price;
        this.baseCurrency = baseCurrency;
    }
}
```

and  the DAO looks like this:

```
package com.amitbaz.tradingsystem;

import org.hibernate.Hibernate;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import java.util.List;

import io.dropwizard.hibernate.AbstractDAO;

public class ProductDAO extends AbstractDAO<Product>{


    public ProductDAO(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        super(sessionFactory);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public List<Product> getAll(){
        return list(namedQuery("com.amitbaz.tradingsystem.product.GetAll"));
    }

    public List<Product> getByName(String name){
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("%");
        builder.append(name).append("%");
        return list(namedQuery("com.amitbaz.tradinsystem.product.GetByName").setParameter("name", builder.toString()));
    }

}
```

I also initialized the hibernateBundle in the application class and registered the resource to the environment:

```
package com.amitbaz.tradingsystem;


import org.glassfish.jersey.server.filter.RolesAllowedDynamicFeature;
import org.hibernate.Hibernate;
import org.skife.jdbi.v2.DBI;

import io.dropwizard.Application;
import io.dropwizard.auth.AuthDynamicFeature;
import io.dropwizard.auth.AuthValueFactoryProvider;
import io.dropwizard.auth.CachingAuthenticator;
import io.dropwizard.auth.basic.BasicCredentialAuthFilter;
import io.dropwizard.auth.basic.BasicCredentials;
import io.dropwizard.db.DataSourceFactory;
import io.dropwizard.db.PooledDataSourceFactory;
import io.dropwizard.hibernate.HibernateBundle;
import io.dropwizard.jdbi.DBIFactory;
import io.dropwizard.setup.Bootstrap;
import io.dropwizard.setup.Environment;

public class TradingSystemApplication extends Application<TradingSystemConfiguration>{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        new TradingSystemApplication().run(args);
    }

    private final HibernateBundle<TradingSystemConfiguration> HibernateBundle = new HibernateBundle<TradingSystemConfiguration>(Product.class){

        @Override
        public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory(TradingSystemConfiguration config) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return config.getDataSourceFactory();
        }


    };



    @Override
    public void initialize(Bootstrap<TradingSystemConfiguration> bootstrap) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        bootstrap.addBundle(HibernateBundle);
    }



    @Override
    public void run(TradingSystemConfiguration config, Environment env) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //final DBIFactory factory = new DBIFactory();
        //final DBI jdbi = factory.build(env, config.getDataSourceFactory(), "mysql");
        //final TestResource testRes = new TestResource();
        //final UserDAO dao = jdbi.onDemand(UserDAO.class);
        final ProductDAO productDAO = new ProductDAO(HibernateBundle.getSessionFactory());
        env.jersey().register(new ProductResource(productDAO));
        env.jersey().register(new TestResource()); 
        env.jersey().register(new AuthDynamicFeature(
                new BasicCredentialAuthFilter.Builder<User>()
                .setAuthenticator(new TradingSystemAuthenticator())
                .setAuthorizer(new TradingSystemAuthorizer())
                .setRealm("SHITTT")
                .buildAuthFilter()));

        env.jersey().register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class);
        env.jersey().register(new AuthValueFactoryProvider.Binder<>(User.class));

    }

}
```

Now, when I'm testing this queries i get an 500 error and `Named query not known: <name of the query>` error in the server logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add javax.persistence @Entity annotation to your product class.

Comment: OMG thank you than you thank you!!! I was trying to user hibernate annotations @ Entity but it is deprecated so i was having troubles in understanding what is the correct import for that... I also changed @ Table applysTo to name and now it works like  charm!